# How to map a yum repository to a certain subdirectory in Artifactory?

Tags: yum, artifactory

I need to implement something similar to:

- http://repo.example.com/distros/centos/5.7/ -> http://vault.centos.org/5.7/
- http://repo.example.com/distros/centos/7.0/ -> http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/
- http://repo.example.com/distros/internal/ (a local Artifactory repository)

I discovered that at least with version 4.1 it seems impossible to map repositories to sub-directories.

[image]
Is this true or there is a workaround for doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use the repository key for achieving this. The repository key is used as a unique identifier for the repository and should not be used for manipulating the request path.
If I understand your requirement correctly, there are 2 possible options I can think of:

1. Change the value of ["YUM Metadata Folder Depth"](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/YUM+Repositories#YUMRepositories-LocalRepositories) to 1 so Yum metadata will be kept in one level from the root of the repository. This will allow to manage multiple sets of Yum metadata in one repository under different paths.
2. Use an HTTP proxy such as NginX in front of Artifactory and map the required paths to multiple Yum repositories in Artifactory

Comment: Indeed, if you are only storing yum repositories inside the same path and all of them are at the same *path depth* this works very well. I was lucky enough that this was my case. Still for a generic solution, people should vote/comment on the feature request from https://www.jfrog.com/jira/browse/RTFACT-8683

Answer (score 0):

It seems that's a limitation of the product so I ended up having to raise this bug: https://www.jfrog.com/jira/browse/RTFACT-8683